# Minimizing a function which contains the floor function

Tags: optimization, education, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I've the function ($A>1$ is a real positive variable; $F= \lfloor A \rfloor$ and $F \ge 1$ because $A>1$):

$$ U = \frac {F + (A - F)^2 } {A} $$

How can I minimize that function? In my old notes about this, the procedure is: (i) choose $F=1$ (why?); (ii) do the derivative $dU/dA$; (iii) replace the right value of A in U.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this elementary, without calculus. We want to minimize the function
$ f: (1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R} $ with

$$ f(x)=\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor+(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)^2}{x} $$

Notice that $ \lfloor x \rfloor \geq 1 $ and using AM-GM:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor+(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)^2}{x} &= \frac{x^2+\lfloor x \rfloor+\lfloor x \rfloor^2-2x\lfloor x \rfloor}{x}\\
&\geq \frac{2x\sqrt{\lfloor x \rfloor+\lfloor x \rfloor^2}-2x\lfloor x \rfloor}{x}\\
&=2\left(\sqrt{\lfloor x \rfloor+\lfloor x \rfloor^2}-\lfloor x \rfloor\right)\\
&=\frac{2\lfloor x \rfloor}{\sqrt{\lfloor x \rfloor+\lfloor x \rfloor^2}+\lfloor x \rfloor}\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor}+1}+1}\\
&\geq \frac{2}{\sqrt{1+1}+1}\\
&=2(\sqrt{2}-1)
\end{aligned}
$$

This value is attained when $ \lfloor x \rfloor = 1 $ and $ x^2=\lfloor x \rfloor+\lfloor x \rfloor^2=2 $ which gives $ x=\sqrt{2} $.

Comment: Hello @Atticus thank you very much for your elegant answer.

Comment: PS: can you explicit the steps to go from 3 row to 4 row please?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi, that is just $$\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}=\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}$$. So $$\sqrt{\lfloor x \rfloor+\lfloor x \rfloor^2}-\lfloor x \rfloor = \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor+\lfloor x \rfloor^2-\lfloor x \rfloor^2}{\sqrt{\lfloor x \rfloor+\lfloor x \rfloor^2}+\lfloor x \rfloor}=\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{\sqrt{\lfloor x \rfloor+\lfloor x \rfloor^2}+\lfloor x \rfloor}$$

Comment: Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

Using the accepted answer's notation

$$f(x)=\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor+(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)^2}{x}$$

If $n$ is a positive integer and $x=n$, note that $f(n) = 1$.

Can we make $f$ smaller with a non-integer value of $x$?

If we restrict the domain of $f$ to $x \in (n, n+1)$. Then

$$\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{n+(x-n)^2}{x}$$

is differentiable. We find

$$f'(x) = \dfrac{x^2-n-n^2}{x^2}$$

and $f'(x) = 0 \implies x = \sqrt{n^2+n}$.

Of course, for this answer to be valid, we need to have
$n < \sqrt{n^2+n} < n+ 1$
which is always going to be true for positive integer values of $n$.

So, the minimum value of $f(x)$ when $n < x < n+1$ is

\begin{align}
   f\left(\sqrt{n^2+n}\right) 
      &= \frac{n+\left(\sqrt{n^2+n}-n \right)^2}{\sqrt{n^2+n}} \\
      &= \frac{n+(n^2+n) - 2n\sqrt{n^2+n} + n^2}{\sqrt{n^2+n}} \\
      &= \frac{2(n^2+n) - 2n\sqrt{n^2+n}}{\sqrt{n^2+n}} \\
      &= 2\sqrt{n^2+n}-2n \\
\end{align}

A quick check shows that the function $x \mapsto 2\sqrt{x^2+x} - 2x$ is strictly increasing on $(0, \infty)$. So the integer value of $n$ that minimizes $f(x)$ occurs when $n=1$; which gives us

$$\text{$x = \sqrt 2$ and $f(x) = 2\sqrt 2 -2$}$$

Comment: Hi @stevengregory, thank you for your alternative solution.